# Отступ от строки знаков препинания

Tags: c#, list, join

Есть список

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(){"Привет",",","дорогой","друг","."};
```

Я перевожу список в строку.

```
var data = string.Join(" ", lst);
```

Как и следовало ожидать выходная строка получилась

```
Привет , дорогой друг .
```

Мне не особо нравится что запятые слишком далеко от текста. Можно ли как то не применять `Join` к знакам препинания?

Comment: а как вы получили этот список?

Comment: Я его придумал.

Comment: Может подклеить запятую и точку к предыдущему слову `{"Привет,","дорогой","друг."}`? Или всё сложнее?

Comment: _Можно ли как то не применять Join к знакам препинания?_ нет, _Join_ не смотрит на значение элементов, он просто бежит по ним и соединяет через указанный разделитель

Comment: @Bald56rus, если вначале имеем список - нет смысла использовать регулярки, проще самому собрать нужную строку, в цикле или используя Aggregate, например

Comment: @Radzhab, как вы определяете является ли символ знаком препинания?

Comment: Ну думаю юзать еще один лист отдельно из знаков препинания

Comment: можно написать отдельный метод(просто метод, метод-расширение, статический метод) который будет выполнять данную работу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(){"Привет",",","дорогой","друг","."};

//массив символов
//для исключения пробела между ними
var excludes = new HashSet<string> {",","."};

var result = string.Empty;

foreach(var s in lst)
{
    result += excludes.Contains(s) ? s : String.Concat(" ", s);
}
```

результат будет следующий: *Привет, дорогой друг.*

пример [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FFwt6M)

---

как заметили в коментариях лучше оформить это методом расширений например так:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string НазваниеМетода(this List<string>, HashSet<string> punctuations)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach(var s in lst)
        {
            result += punctuations.Contains(s) ? s : String.Concat(" ",s);
        }
        return result;
    }    
}
```

применять это надо будет так:

```
var result = lst.НазваниеМетода(excludes);
```

результат будет тот же самый

Comment: для `excludes` вместо _List_ лучше _HashSet_ использовать

Comment: _"s.Length == 1"_ -- в конце предложения вместо . может быть ?!

Comment: @Stack спасибо поправил

Answer (score 2):

Еще, как вариант, можно [посмотреть реализацию Join](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,fa961ce440526a4d), и немного дополнить ее

```
public static string JoinWithPunct(this IEnumerable<string> src, string separator, HashSet<string> puncts)
{
    using (var en = src.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!en.MoveNext())
            return String.Empty;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        if (en.Current != null)
            builder.Append(en.Current);

        while (en.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!puncts.Contains(en.Current))//если не разделитель
            {
                builder.Append(separator);//то добавляем разделитель
            }
            builder.Append(en.Current);
        }
        return builder.ToString();

    }
}
```